# Load *.rb file in Pry REPL

Tags: ruby, pry

I have `my_code.rb` file with some Ruby code:

```rb
class Useful
  def self.perfom_useful_processing(arg)
    arg + 1
  end
end
important_number = 42
```

How can I load that file in Pry REPL, without modifying the file? So that I can do something like that:

```
[1] pry(main)> load "my_code.rb" #<-- This will not work: "LoadError: cannot load such file -- my_code.rb"
[2] pry(main)> Useful.perfom_useful_processing(important_number)
=> 43
```

Comment: From the docs of `Kernel#load`: _Loads and executes the Ruby program in the file filename. If the filename does not resolve to an absolute path, the file is searched for in the library directories listed in `$:`._ Do you call `load` with an absolute filename? Or is the file stored in a directory that is listed in `$:`?

Comment: Are you running pry from the same directory as the file? Your code works as is for me.

Comment: Thanks :) I was running Pry, from different directory than the file. Now the `load` method is loading the file, but `Useful.perfom_useful_processing(important_number)` gives me  `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'important_number' for main:Object`.

Comment: @ArtuX local variables defined in a file, are not accessible from elsewhere. You can use a contant though.

Answer (score 0):

```
% pry -r ./my_code.rb
```

As @max_pleaner points out local variables defined in one file are not be accessible from the other file. A Pry session is a file named `(pry)`, so it doesn't know anything about `important_number`, which is expected.